# How can I edit the boundary in android multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

```
private void jsonUpload(String json) {
    json=json.replace("\\","");
    byte[] file = new byte[0];
    try {
        file = json.getBytes("UTF_8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(file);
    MultipartBody.Part uploadFile = Part.createFormData("resourceInfoList", "blob", requestFile);
    AifricaRetrofitTool.getAPIWithHeader().uploadJson(uploadFile)
            .enqueue(RetrofitTool.getCallback(new UploadJsonRequestCallback()));
}
```

I am trying to upload a file using the post method with android. However, an error occurs because a hyphen is not included in the boundary value after the Content-type, which is automatically added to the header. I want to add two hyphens to this header value.

Answer (score 0):

I use multipart to upload image :

```
File image3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"YOUR_FILE_NAME".jpg");
        String path3 = image3.getPath();
        File file3 = new File(path3);
        // Parsing any Media type file
        RequestBody requestBody3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file3);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload3 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename", file3.getName(), requestBody3);
        RequestBody filename3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), image3.getName());
```

in Retrofit Call method :

```
UploadImage3(fileToUpload1,filename3);
```

Comment: is it edit my boundary?